# How do I add a hyperlink in my app?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uibutton, hyperlink, uitextview

I've tried a number of methods:

- A UIWebView doesn't do the trick because I've got a textured background, and the UIWebView doesn't do transparent backgrounds.
- A UITextView - seems like a really good option. I've got it auto detecting my hyperlink, but it overrides my link colour with blue. :(
- I've looked at the Three20 code - this looks overly complex.

I was thinking, is there a way to make a UIButton look like text? This'd probably be perfect.

This is really annoying, seems that almost every app does this, yet I can't find out how it's done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIWebView` *does* allow transparent backgrounds.

I use this in my app, [Pocket Tabs](http://pockettabs.com).

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'm such an idiot! All I need to do now then, is work out how to override the hyperlink action on pressing of the link :)

Comment: You can do that to!  Add a custom scheme (like http:, but your own) and then handle the webView delegate method:

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

and check for your custom scheme.  Don't think you're an idiot, I'm finding myself facepalm on silly things all the time.  A 2nd pair of eyes really helps.